# Ruby on rails, cancan and default role assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, default, roles, cancan, role

I have built a small ruby webservice, in this I have implemented cancan authorization.

I followed [this tutorial](http://starqle.com/articles/rails-3-authentication-and-authorization-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2/). The problem is that, I can't find out the way to assign at the user, when they do the registration to my site, the base role level.

I find out to do this with a checkbox, but it's not what I want. My idea was to put this assignment directly into the registrations_controller, but I failed to save the role.

I hope that somebody can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post code from your registration controller please? Also your user model if you don't mind. What error messages do you get when things fail? What console output do you see?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what worked for me

user.rb:

```
  after_create :default_role

  private
  def default_role
    self.roles << Role.where(:name => 'User').first
  end
```

Comment: Like others, I was following Tony Amoyal's excellent tutorial, but walked into this! Works great - wish it was in the Amoyal blog post

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but I am using embedded association from rbates:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association

`user.rb:`

`before_create :default_role`

```
private
def default_role
 self.roles = ['client']
end
```

Works like a charm, but pay attention that the hook is **before_create**, not after_create, because the before_create runs just before the insert operation.
The after_create is after the insert operation, which in my case is late.

Answer (score 0):

I have rebuild the migration, I have unified the user and role tables, so now I can assign all without problem.

Thank you.

Comment: From your answer isn't clear how you have manage to solve the role assignment

Comment: I know it's a bit of late response, but it was added to models/user.rb, hope it helps someone else too.