# Adding default role to Devise user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, roles, cancan

While trying to add roles-based authentication (using CanCan and Devise) to my project I found that there are two ways to save roles: the first one is "Has and Belongs_to" way and the second one is just saving role in new field in users table.

So, the question is, how can I define deafult user role in the first way and which way should I choose to define deafult role in the second one (setting default role in migration or editing Devise's user controller?)

Also, should I use this method or is it better to use gem instead?

P.S. I've already read Tony Amoyal's tutorial but didn't found an answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation described in Rails AntiPatterns book: http://railsantipatterns.com/

Short answer is: use field in `users` table, set default role using migrations. This way is much simpler. You should not use complex solution just because it can possibly better suit your future needs.

Answer (score 9):

If I understood the question correctly, here is what worked for me: [Ruby on rails, cancan and default role assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052504/ruby-on-rails-cancan-and-default-role-assignment)

Simply add the following into /models/user.rb to assign default role on signup:

```
after_create :default_role

  private
  def default_role
    self.roles << Role.where(:name => 'User').first
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following in user.rb:

```
after_initialize :set_default_role

private

def set_default_role
  self.role ||= :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A very easy users role solution can be implemented using this gem: https://github.com/platform45/easy_roles